# Run jar file in src folder

Tags: java

In my src folder of my project in Netbeans, I have this jar file (JavaApplication2.jar) which I want to run from command in my main project like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

The problem is that I'm not able to reach JavaApplication2.jar after I generated the jar file of my project.

How can I reach JavaApplication2.jar within my project?

I've tried this path but it didn't work :(

```
java -jar C:\Users\Asus\Documents\NetBeansProjects\RunJarFromResources\dist\RunJarFromResources.jar\JavaApplication2.jar
```

Comment: Check the output of the command. Calling `Runtime.exec(...)` returns a `Process` with a dedicated `OutputStream`, which contains the output of running the command. And your path looks strange to me. Are you sure you have a folder named "RunJarFromResources.jar"?

Comment: It's not a folder. It's the executable jar file of my main project. I want to reach JavaApplication2.jar file which I copied it to src folder of my main project before I had cleaned and built my project in netBeans.

Comment: This is the path of my main project C:\Users\Asus\Documents\NetBeansProjects\RunJarFromResources\dist\RunJarFromResources.jar

Comment: try leaving your executable jar the same folder with JavaApplication2.jar and run `java -jar JavaApplication2.jar`

Comment: My JavaApplication2.jar file is compressed in RunJarFromReso‌​urces.jar that's why I'm not able to reach it. Otherwise it works fine when I try JavaApplication2.jar on its own.

Comment: @shb2789 well, that's quite a bit of a different situation. A `.jar`-file is **not** a directory (in fact it's just a renamed zip-folder). You can't execute the additional jar-file without first unpacking it.

Comment: So now, What is the solution to reach JavaApplication2.jar?

Comment: @shb2789 as I've already said: extract it from the containing `.jar`-file before running it or not packaging it at all in the first place.

Comment: Isn't there any why to reach it without unpacking it?

Comment: @shb2789 No. `Application2.jar` is just a compressed bit-sequence in your containing `.jar`-file. You can't read it without decompression. That's how compression works. Considering a `.zip` or `.jar`-file as a directory is not correct.